# Symlinks point to the same executable target, but do different things

Tags: symlink

I have `vim-athena` package (the same is observed for `vim-gtk`) in my Debian machine.

- Running `vim` spawns Vim in the terminal.
- Running `gvim` spawns a new window with Vim in a Athena GUI.

But what is `vim` and `gvim`? Symlinks pointing to a *same* target.

```
$ readlink -e "$(type -p gvim)"
/usr/bin/vim.athena
$ readlink -e "$(type -p vim)"
/usr/bin/vim.athena
```

And that final target is a binary.

```
$ file --brief /usr/bin/vim.athena
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ...
```

**How can it be that `vim` and `gvim` do different things if both resolve to the
same binary?**

Background:
I was changing my default editor via `update-alternatives --config editor`. In
the list, there are `vim.tiny` and `vim.athena`, but even if I select the
latter, Vim always opens in the terminal, not in a separate GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program can take different routes by looking at the
zeroth-argument `argv[0]` (in the present case, `vim` or `gvim`).

Vim does it in [`main.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/main.c#L1815):

```
    params.argv = argv;
    ...

    /* Figure out the way to work from the command name argv[0].
    "vimdiff" starts diff mode, "rvim" sets "restricted", etc. */
    parse_command_name(&params);
    ...

/* Check for: [r][e][g][vi|vim|view][diff][ex[im]] (sort of) */
static void parse_command_name(mparm_T *parmp) {
    char_u *initstr;
    initstr = gettail((char_u *)parmp->argv[0]);
    ...

    /* "gvim" starts the GUI.  Also accept "Gvim" for MS-Windows. */
    if (TOLOWER_ASC(initstr[0]) == 'g') {
        main_start_gui();
```

In this fragment, the program checks if the first char of the basename of
`argv[0]` is "g"; if yes, it starts the GUI.

This can be observed by creating links:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/vim.athena vimX
ln -s /usr/bin/vim.athena gvimX
ln -s /usr/bin/vim.athena evimX
ln -s /usr/bin/vim.athena rvimX
ln -s /usr/bin/vim.athena exX
```

where `X` is whatever, and then `./vimX` runs Vim in the terminal, `./gvimX`
in the GUI, `./evimX` runs Vim in easy mode, etc.

Comment: You can see similar things with other tools. Bash, for example, behaves differently (activates POSIX mode) if you call it from a symlnk named `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: @terdon, the machinery behind it is the same. Heck, you could even write shell scripts that behave differently depending on the name by which they are called.

Comment: @vonbrand yes, of course. I just felt that since `sh`/`bash` is a very well known example, it might be worth pointing out.